# execute code on start of app engine endpoints

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints

Is there a way to start a piece of code on-start of GAE using Endpoints java?
I know by using servlets we can do that, but using endpoints is it possible? If yes, then how should I proceed. 
Can't find anything around this. I am new to GAE.
Basically, I want to run an init method as soon as the server starts. 
I am using Android Studio for developing this server so it's NOT the latest V2 endpoints.

Comment: Are you saying you want to execute an Endpoints method on start, or just some arbitrary code?

Comment: I want to know if I can execute any code of mine like some configuration setting as soon as server starts using endpoints. I don't want to use servlets. Is there any method api for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [warmup requests and a ServletContextListener](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/warmup-requests/configuring).